# Cannot call a method of const reference parameter in C++

Tags: c++, function, class, methods, constants

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){};
    ~A(){};
    void method(){};

};

void call(const A &a)
{
    a.method();   // I cannot call this method here if I use "const" but I can call it if not using "const"
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    call(a);
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, the error is: "`passing const A as this argument of void A::method() discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|`"

In function `call`, if I use `const`, I get the error, but if I get rid of it, it works.

Can anyone explain it for me?

Comment: See [What is a “const member function”?](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-member-fns). Also, you don't need `;` after your member function definitions.

Comment: What do you think the `const` does?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thank you for your answer but this rule does not work with the overloading operator [] as mentioned in this link, can you explain more for me?

http://pastebin.com/1mKek7pM

Sorry for this inconvinience. I actually don't know how to create a code block in this comment area.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit as I know, it ensures that we cannot change anything of the object. I try the rule "void method() const {};" for overloading operator [] but i doesn't work. Can you explain it for me?
Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/1mKek7pM

Comment: @MrCold: The only reason that code doesn't work is because you have a bug in the `operator[]` that you randomly added and that has nothing to do with this question. Try to change just _one thing at a time_ when you are trying to solve problems. If you'd _only_ added the `const` to `method()`, you'd have seen that it works fine.

Comment: Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I use Absolute C++, Walter Savitch , 2nd, 2005

Comment: @MrCold: How many times have you read it so far

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I read it about one year ago, and today I re-read it for my assignment in class.

Comment: You read it all in one day?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, I mean i read the section related to this post, not the whole book

Comment: Ah. So now we have found the problem. :)

Answer (score 28):

You can't call non-const member functions via const references. You can fix this by making the member function `const`:

```
void method() const {};
              ^^^^^
```

This indicates that calling the member does not mutate the object it is called on<sup>*</sup>

<sup>* Conceptually. In practice it can mutate members marked `mutable`</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this as I see this rule does not work with overloading operator [] as follow: http://pastebin.com/1mKek7pM
Can you explain more?

Comment: @MrCold What do you mean "this rule doesn't work"? Do you mean it doesn't compile? That is because you are returning a non-const reference to a data member via a const reference to the object.

Comment: @MrCold In other words, the const overload should return a `const` reference (or a value): `const int& operator [] (int i) const {return num;}`. You can also add a non-const overload for when you want to be able to modify the data member: `int& operator [] (int i) {return num;}`